# How to use locally produced NuGet in a docker image?

Tags: c#, docker, asp.net-core, nuget, nuget-package-restore

I have a use case where I have a .nupkg file already generated locally on my machine.
I want to use this local nuget file in the docker image. Below is how existing docker file looks like -

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1 AS build
WORKDIR /app

RUN mkdir -p /nuget
ADD nuget /nuget/

COPY src/*.csproj .
RUN dotnet restore

COPY src/ .
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1 AS runtime
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build /app/out ./
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "EdgeService.dll"]
```

So in the `RUN dotnet restore` step it fetches a particular nuget package from nuget.org repository and builds the image. I want a mechanism by which it could use a .nupkg file which I have on my local machine instead of it fetching from nuget server.

Is there some change I could do in the .csproj file or the docker file to make sure that it happens?
Is it necessary to setup a local nuget server in this case?

Answer (score 2):

Below are the changes I did to get it working -

Dockerfile changes -

```
RUN mkdir -p /nuget
ADD Nuget /tmp/Nuget

COPY src/*.csproj .
RUN dotnet restore
```

Changes in the .csproj file -

```
<RestoreSources>$(RestoreSources);https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json;/tmp/Nuget</RestoreSources>
```

And in the Nuget folder I copied the .nupkg file which I wanted to be referenced by the docker image.

Comment: this is not working in my case with dockerfile

Answer (score 1):

Yes you need a nuget server running somewhere. Local is great, until you want to set up CI and then you need a hosted one. I used a hosted docker container with a nuget server in it before later migrating to GitHub packages.

After a while of running this set up however I found rebuilding packages for every change a pain so I rearchiteced my solution to not need private NuGet packages at all.

Comment: But what change in I need to do in the dockerfile or anywhere else to force it to use local nuget server instead of nuget.org to fetch the nugget?...why can't it use a specific Nuget (.nupkg file) which is copied in the same directory or anywhere locally?

Comment: You can use a NuGet.config file and copy that in from the docker file. That NuGet.config will direct the build to your local server.

Comment: @KumarPallav - Specify `RestoreSources` in your `.csproj`. Example: `<RestoreSources>$(RestoreSources);absolute-path-to-my-solution-in-the-docker-image/;https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json</RestoreSources>` You will need to copy the package to the Docker image before `dotnet restore` as the location must be accessible while running inside the container. A simpler solution is to just have your package `unlisted` at nuget.org.

Comment: @JohnHanley - RestoreSources tweak which you are suggesting will save me from the creation of local private nuget server. I will try this and let you know. Thanks :)

Comment: @JohnHanley - I added this line in the .csproj file under PropertyGroup -<RestoreSources>$(RestoreSources);https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json;/nuget</RestoreSources> ......after that i tried building the docker image...i get the error saying   Determining projects to restore...
/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/3.1.402/NuGet.targets(128,5): error : The local source '/nuget' doesn't exist. [/app/EdgeService.csproj]   I have created folder named 'nuget' and inside that I have the .nupkg file I want to use in docker image.....Please guide :)

Comment: Did you create the folder `/nuget` in the Docker image and copy the package there?

Comment: @JohnHanley - I have modified the Dockerfile to create /nuget folder in the docker image and copy contents of the folder(i.e.. .nupkg file) in the docker image....I am now getting this error when I run the docker file -  Determining projects to restore...
/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/3.1.402/NuGet.targets(128,5): error : The local source '/tmp/Nuget' doesn't exist. [/app/EdgeService.csproj]
Removing intermediate container 4b9ecf75884f

Comment: It seems to be working now. Thanks a lot @JohnHanley

Comment: @KumarPallav Post an answer with the changes that you made. This will help others.

Comment: @KumarPallav can you please post your answer with changes because I am also running in the same situation